# Stop page from redirecting after form submission in Django

Tags: python, ajax, django, python-2.7, django-forms

I am using django and I have created an app in which I want to upload a zip file which is saved in a specific location (At this point my django server is localhost)
I have the following code which is working fine:

This is my HTML Template:

```
<form id="saveZipFile" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="docfile" id="docfile">
    <input type="submit" id="upload-button" value="Upload">
</form>
```

This is my forms.py:

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField()
```

This is my views.py:

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open('uploaded_zip.zip', 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)


def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['docfile'])
            return HttpResponse()
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
        return HttpResponse()
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^upload_file/$', views.upload_file, name='upload_file'),
]
```

But in the end, the url is changing to `/upload_file` - which is correct as I understand - and that page is empty (since I am returning an empty `HttpResponse`)

I am trying to build a Single-Page-Application and this redirection is throwing the entire state of my web-page out of the window.

Is there any way in which I can possible make an AJAX call instead of using django forms?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I did add an ajax call that gets the uploaded file and sends it to the django view.

AJAX call:

```
var selectedFile = $('#docfile').files[0];

var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("file", selectedFile);
$.ajax({method: 'POST', 
        url: 'upload_file',
        data: fd, 
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined, 
                  'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken')
        },
        cache: false, 
        processData: false})
        .done(function(data) {
            alert(data)
        });
```

But in the view when I print out `request.POST`, I get this mess (and many, many lines of it):

```
<QueryDict: {u'\x00\x00userapp/.git/objects/0e/34e20fc7131238973f102fe6d2d7fe102d12f4UT\x05\x00\x03\ufffd': [u'\xc0Yux\x0b\x00\x01\x04\xe8\x03\x00\x00\x04\xe8\x03\x00\x00PK\x01\x02\x1e\x03\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x001\x852K\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use ajax for this, retrieve the data from the form, make the request and return false, which prevents the redirect from occurring. It should look this like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'form-submit.php',
            data: { name: $(this).name.value, 
                    surname: $(this).surname.value }
        });
        return false;
    }); 
})
```

Comment: Well, yes. But I have to save the zip file contents as well, right? When I send the zip file contents I get QueryDict full of binary data - and I am not sure what to do of that.

Comment: I investigated a little and when we use django-forms to upload files - the file uploaded becomes an InMemoryUploadedFile object - so calling the in-built django functions to save this file is pretty straightforward. The question arises when you have huge data in the request.POST QueryDict and there does not seem to be a straightforward way to convert that into a .zip file